# Python 3 csv read does not recognize Cyrillic script

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following Python code:

```
from urllib import request

url_base = "https://translate.google.com"
url_params_list = "/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=en&text="

with open('top5000russianlemmasraw.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        url = url_base + url_params_list + request.quote(row[0].encode('cp1251'))

        print(url)
```

The file `top5000russianlemmasraw.csv` is a list of words in Cyrillic script.

The problem with the code is that the Cyrillic script is imported as strings of question marks, e.g. `'????'`, which then get converted to URL code as `'%3F%3F%3F%3F'` type strings. I am not sure how to get Python to import Cyrillic script so that it does not show up as a question mark. Would appreciate help on this.

Comment: You need to open the file using the correct encoding.

Comment: What would be the correct encoding for Cyrillic text in a csv file? I tried to open the file using `windows-1251`, but having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) built-in defaults to the encoding returned by [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding). You can override this with the keyword parameter

```
# ...
with open('top5000russianlemmasraw.csv', encoding='cp1251') as csv_file:
    # ...
```

Or, alternatively you could open the file as bytes and then decode in chunks

```
with open('top5000russianlemmasraw.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    blob = csv_file.read()
    text = blob.decode('cp1251')
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am getting the same result with this encoding.

Comment: The problem was with the file. The above works as expected now.